# SHA-1 fingerprint certificate keytool command returns Illegal Option

Tags: flutter, certificate, fingerprint, keytool

Having problems with the flutter app in generating the Certificate fingerprint using the Keytool.

The command provided by firebase docs

`keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`

is not working and It returns **Illegal Options**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open CMD in Windows (if you are not logged in as admin use - open as admin )

type- `keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore` (eleminate the slash from your code after -v)

Now it will return a field `Enter Keystore password:` use **android** as password.  *while typing it might not show, in case just press enter after entering the password* it should work.